# How to dynamically indicate the start as well as the end of a set of conditions within a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, list-comprehension

I
I seek to create an indicator column in a dataframe that looks at the values of entry and exit column and creates a window that has the following logic:

1. Find earliest date where entry is a 1 (1/3/2019) and mark window as 1.
2. Window remains 1 until exit is 1 (1/5/2019).
3. Window then becomes 0 until it finds the next value of entry that
   equals 1 (1/8/2019).
4. The process is repeated up to most recent date in DataFrame.

So for the Window column an exit must follow and entry or for every entry there will eventually be an exit (see example below).
Also note, the date index is in reverse order.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':[5,3,4,5,4,2,1,4,5,4,2,3],
                    'C2':[3,3,2,3,4,1,3,2,3,5,3,3]},
                   index = pd.date_range('1/1/2019',periods = 12))
df1 = df.iloc[::-1]

# Create function to add entry and exit criteria
def window_range(df):
    crit1 = ((df['C1'] >2) & (df['C1'].shift(-1) < df['C1']))
    crit2 = (df['C2'].shift(-1)==3)
    entry = crit1&crit2
    df['Entry'] = np.where(entry,1,0)
    exit = (df['C1'] < df['C1'].shift(-1))
    df['Exit'] = np.where(exit,1,0)
    return df
df2 = window_range(df1)
df2
# The Column I'd like to add
window = list([1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0])
df2['window'] = pd.Series(window, index=df2.index)
df3 = df2
# Desired Final Output
df3
```

[image]

Comment: Why the `list-comprehension` tag?

Comment: I build most of my code with list comprehensions when I can. At this point, I'd take any solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it fits your criteria, but the desired output doesn't mach yours. According to the rules you set there should only be two rows with window = 1.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':[5,3,4,5,4,2,1,4,5,4,2,3],
                    'C2':[3,3,2,3,4,1,3,2,3,5,3,3]},
                   index = pd.date_range('1/1/2019',periods = 12))

df2 = window_range(df)  # using your func

res, window = [], False
for row in df2.iterrows():
    if row[1]['Entry']:
        window = True
    if row[1]['Exit']:
        window = False
    res.append(window)
df2['window'] = numpy.array(res).astype(int)
df2


           C1  C2 Entry Exit window
2019-01-01  5   3   1   0   1
2019-01-02  3   3   0   1   0
2019-01-03  4   2   0   1   0
2019-01-04  5   3   0   0   0
2019-01-05  4   4   0   0   0
2019-01-06  2   1   0   0   0
2019-01-07  1   3   0   1   0
2019-01-08  4   2   0   1   0
2019-01-09  5   3   0   0   0
2019-01-10  4   5   1   0   1
2019-01-11  2   3   0   1   0
2019-01-12  3   3   0   0   0
```

Comment: Hey Josh thanks for the response. What I am looking for is that window will remain in the entry state until it finds the next exit ==1 where exit must follow an entry. The goal is to collect the observations between two dates, where entry is always the first date. Sorry it was not clear.

Comment: But isn't that the case here? row 1 entry, row 2 exit so 0. then 0 until third-last row which is entrance, then exit so 0 for last 2 rows. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know if it is because I have to work with the data in reverse order, but I think of it as progressing from the earliest date to the most recent date. So thrid row from bottom entry is 1 so window should be 1 then window remains 1 up the date in which exit is 1 moving our way up the dates until we reach the most recent date which is row 1.

Comment: I hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still almost certain you have an error in your question

Comment: Thanks I'll consider rewriting with hopefully a better more general example.